# Is it possible have OR condition in excel decision table

Tags: drools, rules, redhat-decision-manager

I am new to drools and I am exploring the decision table. I want to OR two columns in the decision table is it possible? Please go through the example it will help to understand my question and what I wanted to achieve.

This is my decision table :
[image: Excel decision table]

It will generate the following rule where each column is separated by AND.

```
rule "Simple Customer Categorization_10"
    when
        $c: LoanRequest(noCibil == "true", gender.equalsIgnoreCase("F"), type.equalsIgnoreCase("REGULAR"), amount <= 30)
    then
        $c.setRate(7.3);
end
```

However is it possible to have **OR** condition in the rule or **how to modify my decision table such that the following rule is generated**?

```
rule "Simple Customer Categorization_10"
    when
        $c: LoanRequest(noCibil == "true", gender.equalsIgnoreCase("F") || type.equalsIgnoreCase("REGULAR"), amount <= 30)
    then
        $c.setRate(7.3);
end
```

Can I also do the same in the guided decision table as well?

**Note:** I understand that rules should be atomic and reduced to the simplest form but this is to understand what can/can't be done with the decision table.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it's not supported, since you should have 2 rules -- one for the Gender case and one for the Type case.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas totally agree with you but that is making them atomic please read the note at end of my question.

Comment: That's not what "atomic" means. They're not even mutually exclusive. I'm only commenting that it wouldn't surprise me that the operation weren't supported.